# Types of numbers

Tags: grammatical-number

I know of four types of numbers:

> -cardinal (e.g. one, 5, ninteen)
>
> -ordinal (e.g. 1st, second, 23rd)
>
> -nominal (e.g. player 5, zip code: 87558)(i.e used define a term rather than give a relative position.)
>
> -and a fourth that indicates how many times something has been done. (E.g. Once, twice)

Each of these types of numbers, other than the fourth category, can be written as neumerals or spelled out, but what is the name of the fourth category?

Comment: I don't think that it has a specific name, since there are only three words (*once, twice, thrice*) that fall under the category. Also note that all three come from the Anglo-Saxon genitive of the corresponding cardinals; i.e. *once* literally means *of one (time)*.

Comment: Cardinal, ordinal and nominal. https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/cardinal-ordinal-nominal.html

Comment: @Lambie If nominal is a name I don't see how it fits.

Comment: "How many times it has been done" is still a cardinal.  We don't really have a third system in English.  *Once, twice*, maybe *thrice*, but then what?  27 times, the same construction as 27 apples.

Comment: Perhaps you need to go and visit the site I posted in order to understand. It provides very simple examples with pictures.

Comment: @Lambie I think perhaps you should recheck your own reference.  It states *A Nominal Number is a number used only as a name, or to identify something (not as an actual value or position). Examples: the number on the back of a footballer ("8"); a postal code ("91210"), a model number ("380")*  Those do not correspond to OP's 3rd category (*once, twice, ...*)

Comment: Oh boy. The asker said there are three types of numbers and the one the asker was missing was **nominal**. Numbers used to NAME something. Furthermore, the asker is confused about ordinal and cardinal. ERGO, I thought a little trip down the math memory lane was in order. All three are succinctly explained and then I don't have to do the work. Get it??

Comment: Okay, I will change the list so that there are four categories -nominal now included-. Thank you for informing me of this. Do you know if the current third category has a name though?

Comment: There are only THREE, Morella. You have now changed the question and it is wrong. You mixed up the definitions: cardinal: numbers on the number line ordinal: numbers that provide an order, first, second, third; nominal: numbers used to call something by: Player 8, Player 2. Once or twice for doing things is an adjective or noun and is **ordinal**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adverbial_number)*:

> **adverbial number** ‎(*plural* **adverbial numbers**)
>
> 1. (*grammar*) A word that expresses a countable number of times
>
> > "Twice" is an **adverbial number**, while "two" is a cardinal number.

Wikipedia has a discussion of adverbial number in, of all languages, [Romanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_numbers#Adverbial_numbers).

Comment: And Icelandic has *þrisvar* for thrice.